# Dark vs Darkness

Tags: word-usage

I have a usage related doubt about using 'Dark' in the following sentence:

```
Each time, when he switches on the light, he is surprised how it vanishes ______ completely.
```

'Darkness' fits well here, but does 'dark' work too, as it is also a noun?

Comment: You may need to re-read/revise your question, as neither "...he is surprised how it vanishes dark completely..." nor "...he is surprised how it vanishes darkness completely..." make sense!

Comment: Specifically, I would say there is a missing article *the* after the word vanishes.

Comment: I've given an answer below, but this and questions like it would be better on our sister site English Language Learners.

Comment: _vanquishes_ [http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vanquish] might fit better than _vanishes_.  And use of _the_ before either _dark_ or _darkness_ would be preferred, as stated above.

Answer (score 2):

Most importantly, what is incorrect in both the examples is that 'vanish' is an intransitive verb. It cannot be used transitively as you have done.

'He vanished the coin' does not make sense, as it is the coin which 'vanishes'. So one needs to say 'he made the coin vanish'.

Similarly you cannot say '...it vanishes the darkness completely'. You need to say '...the darkness vanishes completely', or '...it makes the darkness vanish completely'.

On the more minor point about dark v darkness, I think 'darkness' is the more literate and elegant word to use. However I do not rule out that many people would say 'it makes the dark vanish'. 'Dark' is certainly used as a noun as well an adjective - but 'darkness' is better.

Comment: People do say vanished in this manner.  It's less common, but they do say it.  [See definition #5](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vanish) with an object.

Comment: In fact:  [See this, too](http://ask.reference.com/web?q=How%20To%20Vanish%20A%20Coin&o=100100)

Comment: @DavidM According to the OED there is a transitive use of the verb 'vanish', but the examples it cites are few and far between. And the OED does confirm that nowadays it is almost exclusive to conjurers.

Comment: I agree, but I wouldn't go so far as to call it wholesale wrong.  It is just the lesser used form.  As always, lesser used does not equal invalid.

Comment: @DavidM apologies for the mis-spelling s/b 'conjuror'.

Comment: @DavidM If I were advising a young person, about to be interviewed to read English at Oxford,  I would counsel against using 'vanish' as a transitive verb, as well as many other things which the OED accepts. Of course it would depend a lot on which particular tutor was doing the interview.

Comment: I won't say that is incorrect advice.  Just, perhaps, a bit prescriptive.

Comment: Again, I will not disagree.  But, a man can use an uncommon construct when speaking.  In fact, I would say that most of us "contributors" on this site, speak in uncommon ways.  It is the overall message and clarity of his thoughts and ideas that makes a man's speech great.  Not his minor grammatical choices.

Comment: @DavidM As the French would say 'theoriquement, oui'!

Comment: You have, as we Americans say, just proven my point.

Answer (score -1):

Making the assumption that you have left out an article (*the*) after vanishes, I would say either is correct.

It is unusual in English to use vanish as verb with an object in this manner, but it is a valid usage.  [See definition #5](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vanish).  The meaning becomes to cause to disappear.  [See this search page entitled How to vanish a coin.](http://ask.reference.com/web?q=How%20To%20Vanish%20A%20Coin&o=100100)

> Each time, when he switches on the light, he is surprised how it vanishes the darkness completely.
>
> Each time, when he switches on the light, he is surprised how it vanishes the dark completely.

Darkness is a noun.  Dark is a noun.  They are effectively synonyms of one another.

That said, to my native ear, darkness has a "better ring to it".  But, there is no grammatical reason why this is true.

Comment: To whomever down voted, see the revision.  The usage is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It's certainly uncommon to see *vanish* being used a transitive verb.

Comment: @reinierpost Uncommon, yes.  Valid, yes.  Uncommonness does not invalidate it.